# Which type of paper do you need to print business cards and should the artwork converted to Cmyk?

Tags: color

Which paper is required to do business cards and why should the colour of the artwork turn to Cmyk while printed?

Comment: as said in the answers, there's a myriad of types of paper for printing business cards, and there's plenty of tutorials on the difference between CMYK / RGB, so I'm flagging this question as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of paper for printing business card like **Glossy Stocks, Matte Stocks, Photo Card Stocks, Card Stock** its papers depend on your design and feel. Lab color has only three color RGB (RED-GREEN-BLUE), the photos are printing from the lab, but when you print visiting card you must print them from printing press they have four color CMYK (cyan, magenta, yellow and key). That's why you should convert your color to CMYK.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous types of paper used for business cards, any commercial printer (even FedEx/Kinkos or Staples) will give you many options. The important thing is the weight/thickness of the paper. Commonly known as "cardstock", a thicker paper is sturdier, and more aesthetically pleasing. At no time would you want to present a business card on regular 80lb. Text paper (like you'd use in an inkjet printer). Talk to your printer for options.

As far as color, there are myriad articles explaining the differences (Google: [CMYK vs. RGB](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmyk%20vs%20rgb&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)) and when to use each. However, in many cases Spot colors are the better choice for business cards. Most companies' logos/design standards use a combination of spot (Pantone) colors instead of CMYK. This gives them more specific options of colors, and also allows their printed materials to have a uniform look wherever they are printed, because the printer is using a very specific ink color instead of trying to match a color using the CMYK combination (which can vary greatly on different printing presses). More on Pantone spot colors here: [CMYK vs. RGB vs. Pantone](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmyk%20vs%20rgb&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=cmyk%20vs%20rgb%20vs%20pantone). Again, conversations with your local printer will give you the best information.